# async executor `this` not defined typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
class Executor {
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  steps: { (): Promise<void> }[];

  constructor(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    this.name = 'chartNoteFaxing';
    console.log(`Setting startDate ${startDate} and endDate: ${endDate}`);
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    console.log(`this.startDate ${this.startDate} this.endDate: ${this.endDate}`);
    this.steps = [
      this.sayHi,
    ];
  }

  async sayHi() {
    console.log('GOT HERE???')
    console.log(`${this}`);
    console.log(`Hi! Got to here with ${this.name}`);
  }

  async execute() {
    for (const step of this.steps) {
      console.log('About to run step');
      console.log(`${this}`);
      await step();
    }
  }  
}
```

and for some reason here is the output:

```
[LOG]: "Setting startDate Mon Nov 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) and endDate: Mon Nov 28 2022 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" 
[LOG]: "this.startDate Mon Nov 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) this.endDate: Mon Nov 28 2022 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" 
[LOG]: "About to run step" 
[LOG]: "[object Object]" 
[LOG]: "GOT HERE???" 
[LOG]: "undefined"
```

Obviously, the issue in the `sayHi` method is that `this` is undefined. It's even more strange, because it's defined right before the `await step()`. I'm not sure why. The class has been instantiated so why would referencing `this` in typescript break it?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be a good link. So you're saying I could do something like `this.sayHi.bind(this)` in the constructor? That seems.... oddd

Comment: `this.steps = [this.sayHi.bind(this)];` or `this.steps = [() => this.sayHi()];` would work. The problem is that putting `this.sayHi` into an array apparently loses connection to knowing what `this` is. This is more common seen passing a class method into other code, like `setTimeout(this.sayHi, 20)`.